# Mac OS Sierra cannot start MySQL

Tags: mysql, mac

MySQL starts fine at OS stat up.

Stopping it and then starting again has an issue though.

I am using:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

The executable binary file is located in:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

It just gets stuck with this message for minutes and minutes:

```
Starting MySQL.................................................
```

Only restarting the whole machine results in it working again.

Attempting to stop the service using

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Results in this error message:

```
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
```

Comment: Can you check the `pid` of `mysql`? Looks like it is having issues. Can you run this command `/etc/init.d/mysql status` and let me know if you are seeing an error?

Comment: init.d doesn't exist

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255671/error-mysql-server-pid-file-could-not-be-found same as yours?

Answer (score 1):

High Sierra user here. I had a similar issue.

I fixed it by checking out this directory's contents:

```
cd /usr/local/mysql/data 
ls -l
```

to see if everything was owned by _mysql (Hint: second column of the output you get). This wasn't the case for me. So I ran the following command:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data/*
```

to change to the proper ownership settings. (Note: I'm on my admin account so I had to prepend with `sudo` for it to work. Otherwise I'd get an `Operation not permitted` error)

[I glanced back after running chown and, as you can see here, mySQL was back in business](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqDtK.png)